# creating primary key based on date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a unique ID for each record based on the date the record is created. Example, if the record is created today, I want the key to be 20101130XX where XX would be a sequential list of numbers such as 01, 02, 03 etc... in case more than one person creates a record today.

If 3 people created records yesterday their unique IDs would be

2011032700
2011032701
2011032702

and then midnight comes and someone creates a new record it would be

2011032800

The purpose of this is to give each record a unique ID that will be used to reference the ticket.

We are already using the date format, but currently users are having to manually enter the id and that can create errors such as 2012032700 when it should have been 2011032700 so instead of putting 2011 they put 2012

I am just not sure how to create a trigger to generate this type of unique ID and would appreciate any assistance

Comment: Why not add seconds to the date as well? That way you don`t need the sequential numbering.

Comment: @Elad, what happens when you get two tickets created during the same second?  And you, @user, what happens when you get more than 99 tickets in a single day?

Comment: Oh... Sorry, I was sure you added the hours and minutes already. Well, you can add the hours and minutes and seconds and also miliseconds, if seconds are not granular enough.

Comment: What is the benefit of using that as an id? Why not use simple auto increment id, and avoid all collsion possibilities. Not worth the effort, I think.

Comment: @Briedis: I was thinking this serves a double perpos. It is both a timestamp and a unique ID.

Comment: This is a small app for a service centre. A single person will be making entries. Also, adding seconds will make the number bigger.

Comment: Adding an autoincrement column will make the table bigger. If this is a small app, seconds should be more than enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From dev.mysql.com: [example-auto-increment.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

For **MyISAM and BDB tables** you can specify **AUTO_INCREMENT** on a **secondary column** in a **multiple-column index**. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

So, make 2 columns on the table, one dateEntered and one (auto_incremented) id, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    dateEntered DATE NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dateEntered, id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

If you don't use ISAM but InnoDB, I think you'll have to write your own trigger that implements this behaviour.

Comment: With this approach, you can present the final ticket number to the user through [`sprintf`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)'s ability to zero-pad data.  `$ticket_number = sprintf('%s%05d', $pre_transformed_date, $foo['id']);` will format the ticket number like `'2011032700001'`, given that you've already converted the date to that format.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, you can then format the (output of) unique id, either in PHP or in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This approach simply won't work because @Charles is true. You can't rely on a timestamp because there's a chance of duplicates (collision).

Create a simple autoincrement id then save the timestamp too and you'll be happy.

Comment: Sorry, no chance two rows are created @ the same milisecond.

Comment: @Elad, MySQL doesn't store milliseconds in the native [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type (or *any* type, for that matter), thus permitting a collision.  (It can calculate them internally, it just can't *store* them.)

Comment: never say never :) I wrote my opinion about i don't like to rely on an uncontrollable variable when i'd like to use it for some special purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What will you do if the number of entries per day exceeds 99? If you strongly want to use "20101130XX" index, I would recommend you use a compound key:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `other_fields` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`id`)
);
```

Comment: but how can I change id to 00 on next date

Answer (score 0):

Just use microtime() to be sure that there are no duplicate entries.

```
function getUniqueID() {
  $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
  return $mt[1] . substr($mt[0], 2, 7);
  }
```

P.S. You can always use lower precision then 7 digits.