# Unique Identifier Mixed Format with Date Prefix (Php / MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, record, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I am creating a ticketing system that will keep track of tickets that a customer creates. The ticket's basic information will be stored in a table 'tickets' who's structure is as follows:

```
  Primary Key (int 255)
  Ticket_Key (varchar)
  Ticket Number (varchar 500)
  Label
  Date Created
  Delete

and so on..
```

The issue is that there will eventually be a large amount of tickets and we need a more uniform way of identifying tickets. I would like PHP to create a Ticket Number in the ticket number that will contain mixed values. The date (in format 20111107), followed by a auto incremented value 1001. 1002, 1003, ...). So the Ticket Number will be 201111071001 for an example.

The issue is how do I program this in PHP to insert to the MySQL database? Also, how do I prevent the possibility of duplicate values in the Unique Id in PHP? There will be a very large amount of customers using the table to insert records.

Comment: If your database supports auto-increment on ID value. YOu could first do an INSERT, then get the new ID and use that to update your ticket number

Comment: @musefan:I first thought about that also. But here's another thing. The ticket number will basically be the date of the ticket followed by the position or order the ticket was created. For an example 201111070001, 201111070002, 201111070003, 20111107000X. Then when the next day comes it will reset like this: 201111080001, and so on. What would I do then?

Comment: I will create an answer so I can explain more detail.

Comment: @musefan : Not to mention that if we let it auto increment on the database. It will be no need to update the ticket number after the first record. There would be no need to update again until the next date. Even then, there would be no way to reset the suffix to 0001.

Comment: See my answer here for an almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455436/creating-primary-key-based-on-date/5455513#5455513 If you don't mind using a MyISAM table, the solution is there.

Comment: It's the same as @liquorvicar proposed.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an auto-increment and combining this with the date field to generate a sequence number for that date and hence a ticketId.

So your insert process would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (...ticket info...)
```

You would then retrieve the auto-increment for this row and run a query like this

```
UPDATE table SET sequence = (SELECT ($id-MAX(auto_increment)) FROM table WHERE date_created=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) WHERE auto_increment=$id
```

You could then easily create a ticketId of format YYYMMDDXXXX. Assuming you never retro-add tickets in the past this would only ever require these two queries even under heavy usage.

[EDIT] Actually, after looking into this there is a much better way to do this natively in MySQL. If you define two columns (date and sequence) and make them a primary key (both columns) with the sequence field as an auto-increment then MySQL will update the sequence column as an auto-increment per date (i.e. it will start with value 1 for each date).

[EDIT] A table structure along these lines would do the job for you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `created_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ticket_sequence` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  [other fields as required]
   PRIMARY KEY  (`created_date`,`ticket_sequence`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When retrieving the data you could then do something like

```
SELECT CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%Y%m%d'),LPAD(ticket_sequence,4,'0')) AS ticket_number, other fields.... FROM table
```

Comment: :Will you please explain to me how you would do this is MySQL? I can't seem to find that.

Comment: The issue is that I need the ticket sequence to reset for each date. For an example on tomorrow's date the ticket sequence should reset to 0001

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu Yes, I understand your requirement, this will work. I have tested it. Try it yourself...

Comment: I don't know if you saw my last response. But if I continue to let the sequence numbers increase with no reset, I eventually get to a very large set to numbers.

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu Have you tried my suggestion to see what happens? The auto-increment will reset per date in the created_date field.

Comment: I have not. But I will the first chance I get.

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu Once you've tried it, if it does what you need, please come back and mark my post as the answer.

Comment: I will make sure that I do.It may be a while.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand that you want to make one result of two different fields like `datefield` and `ticketnumfield`

in mysql you do this through the command:

```
SELECT concat( datefield, ticketnumfeild ) FROM `tbl_name`
```

this query return the result like `201111071001`

Comment: That is actually a great solution like @musefan but, how do I reset the ticketnumfield on the next date? If I keep letting the ticketnumfield continue to increment without a reset, the ticketnumfield would eventually be a very large number.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before where I wanted to refresh the counter for each new day. Unfortunately I do not speak PHP so you will have to settle for explanation and maybe some pseudo code.

Firstly, create a couple of fields in a config file to keep track of your counter. This should be a date field and a number fields...

```
LastCount (Number)
LastCountDate (Date)
```

Then you make sure that your ticket number field in your database table is set to only unique values, so it throws an error if you try to insert a duplicate.

Then in your code, you load your counter values (LastCount and LastCountDate) and you process them like so...

```
newCount = LastCount;

if LastCountDate == Today 
   increment newCount (newCount++)
else
   reset newCount (newCount = 1)
```

you can then use newCount to create your ticket number.

Next, when you try to insert a row, if it is successful, then great. If it fails, then you need to increment newCount again, then try the insert again. Repeat this until the insert is successful (put it in a loop)

Once you have successfully inserted the row, you need to update the database with the Count Values you just used to generate the ticket number - so they are ready for use the next time.

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: :So LastCount and LastCountDate should be fields in the database?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I would put them in a sort of "config" table. Only needs one row that you can keep updating with the new values.

Comment: If you have a large number of people trying to insert into the table you risk concurrency issues with this solution.

Comment: @liquorvicar : Can you explain please?

Comment: @liquorvicar: Why is that a risk?

Comment: You're relying on "trial by error" to make sure you get a unique sequence number. You read the count, increment, try and store it. If this fails you increment and try again. This would work fine if traffic was low but if the site was really busy (or if you got a huge traffic spike) you don't know how many queries it might take each client before they got to a successful insert. Imagine 1000 people all try and submit at once. If they all read the same initial count it will take you over 500,000 inserts to ensure they all get a unique count (even assuming no-one else tries in the meantime).

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu See the edit to my answer. There is a native way to do what you want in MySQL.