# MySQL - convert MyISAM into InnoDB getting error 1075

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to convert a table from MyISAM into InnoDB, this is the definition and I am getting error `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

The table has an AutoIncrement value and the field is indexed and it works with MyISAM.  I am new to InnoDB so it might be a dumb question

```
CREATE TABLE `cart_item` (
 `cart_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `design_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `logo_position_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `subst_style_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `style_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `subst_color_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `color_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `size_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `qty` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
 `date_last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `last_modified_by_id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date_last_locked` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_locked_by_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 `subsite_logo_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bundle` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `color_stop_1` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`,`id`),
 KEY `color_id` (`color_id`),
 KEY `style_id` (`style_id`),
 KEY `size_id` (`size_id`),
 KEY `design_number` (`design_number`),
 KEY `subsite_logo_group_id` (`subsite_logo_group_id`),
 KEY `date_added` (`date_added`),
 KEY `bundle` (`bundle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: This is actually news to me - I did not know that MyISAM would not enforce indexing on auto_increment columns. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you were doing on the MyISAM table, cannot be done with InnoDB. See my answer on a (similar) problem: **[creating primary key based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455436/creating-primary-key-based-on-date/5455513#5455513)**

MySQL docs, in the **[Using `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)** section, explain it:

> For **MyISAM tables** you can specify **`AUTO_INCREMENT`** on a **secondary column** in a **multiple-column index**. In this case, the generated value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

---

You may get similar behaviour in InnoDB but not with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You'll have to use either some fancy trigger or a stored procedure for your Inserts that will take care of the (per `cart_id`) auto-increment.

Comment: :-( OK.. that is what I was afraid of.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have a composite `PRIMARY KEY` defined on `(cart_id, id)`, but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` requires an index on `id` alone. You can add a `KEY` for it (not a primary key, but just a plain index):

```
KEY `idx_id` (`id`)
```

I question the use of the composite PK on `(cart_id, id)` though, since `id` is alone a unique value by definition. Perhaps you should make `id` the PK, and create a separate index across the combination.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY (`cart_id`, `id`)
```

It doesn't even need to be specified as `UNIQUE` because the `AUTO_INCREMENT` can't be repeated anyway.  There is no way to violate uniqueness on the combination `(cart_id, id)`.

Comment: but will the ID increment based on the `cart_id` ?  For example if I enter the touple `(cart_id,id)` `(123,NULL),(123,NULL),(124,NULL)` will I find `(123,1),(123,2),(124,1)` in the database ?

Comment: @Fabrizio No -  the AUTO_INCREMENT column will always increment. You'll get `(123,1),(123,2),(124,3)`

Comment: Thank you, but what I need (for consistency with the current table that is built with `(123,1),(123,2),(124,1)` is the autoincrement to pply only in the primary key like MyISAM does.  Maybe this is not supported in InnoDB ?

Comment: @Fabrizio That is not a functioning auto_increment in innodb.

Comment: Sadly noticed that.  This is a show stopper for my conversion of my ENV to InnoDB.  Thank you

Comment: @Fabrizio I was busy looking up the [correct docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) while ypercube's answer came in

Answer (score 2):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` columns should be define as key, *as what the error implies*.

```
`id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

and set `UNIQUE` on the two column instead of primary key

```
UNIQUE (`cart_id`,`id`),
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3542b/1)

Comment: There is a Fiddle for everything... Thank you.